# How to set to show exact figure

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have one Excel sheet. In that one cell value 65.3333333333333 when I click multiply by 15 [65.3333333333333*15], it just returns 980.00.

How can I change the number format to show 979.99?

Answer (score 1):

On the cell, wrap the multiplication formula with `FLOOR.MATH` function.

```
=FLOOR.MATH(65.3333333333333 * 15, 0.01)
```

The second argument of this function is the significance. Since you need two decimal digit significance, then I use `0.01`. If you need three decimal digit significance, use `0.001` and so on.

---

**Update:**

It works with 12 3s, but does not work with 13 3s.

[image: Screenshot]

Your question use 13 3s, so this won't work. For less than 13 3s, you can use `FLOOR.MATH` to round the `.99999...` to `.99` instead of `1.00`

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the number of digits shown after the decimal place. An easy way to do this is to select the cell and then use the **Increase decimal** button (with right pointing arrow) on the Home tab of the Ribbon:

[image: enter link description here]